# Overriding Customer_Block_Form_Login Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to override the function _prepareLayout() in Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login to stop the title being populated with 'Customer Login' when there's a login area on the page (which is every page).

My config.xml in app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <form_login>My_Module_Block_Customer_Form_Login</form_login>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

My My_Module.xml in app/etc/modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My Login.php in app/code/local/My/Module/Customer/Form/Login.php

```
class My_Module_Block_Customer_Form_Login extends Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login
{

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

I've tried every permutation I can think of but the title still displays 'Customer Login' on the pages where there's a login form and no error logs are being generated.  When I change the function in the core files to the above then it works, so I don't know why it doesn't work when overriding the class?

Any thoughts very welcome!

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below,  which gets rid of the `parent`, else calling `parent::_prepareLayout()` when your class inherits from `Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login` changes nothing to the original behaviour

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    return Mage_Core_Block_Template::_prepareLayout();
}
```